# Get an existing object from a Map with a key

Tags: java, collections, dictionary

For an application written in java (Eclipse), I have created a Map where I save objects of a custom class.

This custom class is called `Music` and has this constructor:

```
public Music (String title, String autor, int code){
    this.setTitle(title);
    this.setAutor(autor);
    this.setCode(code);
}
```

This class has 3 child classes: `Vinyl`, `CD` and `cassette` that extend it. Here is the `CD` class:

```
public CD(String title, String autor, String type, int code) {
    super(title, autor, code);
    this.setType(type);
}
```

Then, in other class called `ManageMusic` I have created some methods and the Map:

```
private final Map<Integer, Music> musicMap;

public ManageMusic() {
    musicMap = new HashMap<Integer, Music>();
}
```

If I want to add an object to the Map, I have a method that basically in this example with the `CD` does:

```
musicItem = new CD(title, autor, format, newCode);
musicMap.put(newCode, musicItem);
```

The code in all theses cases is a number with which I refer to as a determined object to set it into the Map, delete it or get it from the Map.

Now, my question is: When I want to get an object from the Map and set it into a String, I am doing this:

```
String object = musicMap.get(code).toString();
```

This way I should be getting the object from the Map and casting it to a String.

How can I manage the case when the code passed doesn't exist in the Map?

How could I catch an exception or do something to tell the user that there is no element inside the Map with that code?

Comment: I'd kindly recommend you to fix the naming convention of some of the classes, as well as clear up some of the terminology. For instance `ManageMusic` is not a good name for a class. Usually a class name is chosen as a noun, while a method is usually a verb, or a combination of verb(s) and noun(s). In your case, the `ManageMusic` class should probably be called `MusicManager`. Also, do not confuse the `.toString()` call with type casting, as thy are completely different things.

Comment: Ok, I'll take care of that, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Ternary operator](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1300747) `?:`

```
String object = musicMap.get(code) != null ? musicMap.get(code).toString() : "No item found.";
```

**Edit:** (thanks to @user270349)

Even better approach

```
Music m = musicMap.get(code);
String object = (m != null) ? m.toString() : "No item found.";
```

Comment: You are searching the map twice, you can do `Object x; String sA = ((x = m.get("A")) != null) ? x.toString() : "none";` but you need an auxiliary variable.

Comment: @user270349 map's get is much more efficient (its not costly). Still I agree that your solution even better :)

Comment: If you're using two lines, then you should do `Music m = musicMap.get(code)` on the first line rather than the confusing assignment in the middle of the ternary.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the return value of get is null :

```
Music object = musicMap.get(code);
if (object == null) {
    // do nothing
} else {
    String str = object.toString();
}
```

You could also use [containsKey()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29) method :

```
if (musicMap.containsKey(code)) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: what if the map contains the key, there will be an extra method call to get the actual object.

Comment: Yes, that is why I put first snippet on top, as it is preferrable.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understood but you can always do.

```
Music music = musicMap.get(code);
if( music != null )
   String object = music.toString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `containsKey` method:

```
String str;
if(musicMap.containsKey(code)){
    str = musicMap.get(code);
} else {
    // do something
    // str = "some string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to throw an exception when there is no element in map corresponding to key.
This exception can be caught somewhere in your application(depends on how exceptions are handled in your application) this type of implementation allows to easily display different types of error or warning messages to the user.

```
Music object = musicMap.get(code);
if (object != null) {
  // do something
} else {
  throw new NoCDFoundException("no.item.found");
}
```